# Hermite polynomials, prove the solution

Tags: fourier-analysis, bessel-functions

> $
> \text { The Hermite polynomials, } H_{n}(x) \text { , satisfy the following: }  $
>   \begin{array}{l}{\text { i. }<H_{N}, H_{M}>=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^{2}} H_{n}(x) H_{m}(x) d x=\sqrt{\pi} 2^{n} n ! \delta_{n, m}} \\ {\text { ii. } \quad H_{n}^{\prime}(x)=2 n H_{n-1}(x)} \\ {\text { iii. } H_{n+1}(x)=2 x H_{n}(x)-2 n H_{n-1}(x)} \\ {\text { iv. } H_{n}(x)=(-1)^{n} e^{x^{2}} \frac{d^{n}}{d x^{n}}\left(e^{-x^{2}}\right)}\end{array}
>   Using these, show that
>   \begin{array}{l}{\text { a. }\quad H_{n}^{\prime \prime}-2 x H_{n}^{\prime}+2 n H_{n}=0 .\ \text { [Use properties ii. and iii.] }}\end{array}

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) when writing equations, so that they are easier to read. Furthermore, if you show what you were been able to do it may be easier to get an helpful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$H_n^{''}-2xH_n^{'}+2nH_n = (2nH_{n-1})^{'}-4xnH_{n-1}+2nH_n$ (by ii)

= $4n^2 H_{n-2} - 4xnH_{n-1}+2nH_n $ (by ii again)

= $2n(H_n-2xH_{n-1}+2nH_{n-2}) = 0$ (by iii)